# Git: How can I split a branch by file (not by commit)?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-merge, pull-request

**Bottom Line:**

I want to split up a pull request into two smaller pull requests with different subsets of files.  I do not want to split by commit, I want to split by file.

**Details:**

Suppose I have a branch `branch_1`  (off of the `master` branch) in which I've modified 2 files: `file_1` and `file_2`.  Suppose these files were modified together in one or more commits (changes are not separable by commit), and suppose these files do not reference one another in any way.

After some time, I want to merge `branch_1` into `master`, but decide that only `file_1` is ready to be merged.  I may merge `file_2` later, so I put it on a new branch.

So I create a `branch_2` off of `branch_1`.  `branch_2` now contains both the changes to `file_1` and `file_2`.  That's fine, because `branch_2` will be merged after `branch_1` anyway.

Now, how can I nicely revert `branch_1` to remove the changes to `file_2`?

If I just go on `branch_1` and `git checkout master file_2`, it works, BUT: When I merge `branch_1` into `master`, and then `master` into `branch_2`, then it will delete `file_2`.  This is not what I want at all!

Basically I'd like make it as if `file_2` never existed at all on `branch_1`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A slightly more convenient way of selecting specific files:

- create `branch_2` from `master`
- merge `branch_1` into `branch_2` with --no-commit and --squash
- revert specific files you want excluded from the new branch (*)
- commit remaining files in `branch_2`

Now you can either repeat the procedure again with inverse file selection, completely  splitting the two branches right away, or just wait until `branch_2` is merged into `master` and then merge `master` back into `branch_1`, effectively "fast-forwarding" those selected files and excluding them from the original `branch_1`.

(*) many UI-based git clients offer bulk revert tools, making the procedure quite comfortable

EDIT: added --squash option, as else commits from `branch_1` might end up in `master` with only a subset of their actual content

Comment: Dumb follow-up: This loses history, doesn't it? That is, if I change 30 files from CommitA to CommitB, branch at CommitA, merge CommitB with `--no-commit` and `--squash`, then I commit 10 of the files in CommitC and discard the others, I lose the history for those 10 files; there's only CommitC in the log for those files. If I merge the branch at CommitB into my new branch, I "regain" the history of the 20 files I'd discarded in my new branch, but history for those other 10 are [still] gone. Not the end of the world, and mostly expected, I think, but not ideal if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've come to the conclusion that git does not have a nice mechanism for this but it's easy to do using PyCharm (and probably some other tools).

To do it using pycharm, first `git checkout master`, then `git checkout branch_3`, then in Pycharm's Project toolbar right click on the root-folder of your project and go `Git -> Compare with Branch`, select `branch_1`, and then copy over `file_1` from `branch_1`, which you want to merge, into your current code (`branch_3`).  Now you can do a pull request from `branch_3` into `master`.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of making `branch_2` from `branch_1`. I will make `branch_2` from `master`branch and do the changes what you required to merge it to master and then merge `branch_2` to `branch_1`

this is basically [git workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) (nice read here)

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20.  The problem is often you don't realize that the two changes should be on separate branches until they are made.  I am asking what to do when those changes have already been made.

Comment: that's a bit tricky unless you have them in separate commit which you can to generate a `patch` to seperate